# How do I connect ACI to my VM for MongoDB?

Tags: azure, azure-appservice, azure-container-instances

In the Azure portal -> Azure Container Instance -> Container -> log : I saw there's a connection error to the MongoDB like below

```bash
[31m[Nest] 131  - [39m12/04/2023, 2:16:20 AM [31m  ERROR[39m [38;5;3m[MongooseModule] [39m[31mUnable to connect to the database. Retrying (3)...[39m
[31m[Nest] 132  - [39m12/04/2023, 2:16:53 AM [31m  ERROR[39m [38;5;3m[MongooseModule] [39m[31mUnable to connect to the database. Retrying (4)...[39m
[31m[Nest] 131  - [39m12/04/2023, 2:16:53 AM [31m  ERROR[39m [38;5;3m[MongooseModule] [39m[31mUnable to connect to the database. Retrying (4)...[39m
[31m[Nest] 132  - [39m12/04/2023, 2:17:26 AM [31m  ERROR[39m [38;5;3m[MongooseModule] [39m[31mUnable to connect to the database. Retrying (5)...[39m
```

I've created the ACI with public IP and I inbounded this IP address into my MongoDB VM. But it keeps creating such error logs. Is the Public IP I can see in the overview of ACI different from what we usually think it as is? I double check that there's no problem with the network setting in Database inbound rules.

I also put the port `27017` into the ACI setting. Which I'm using to log in into by MongoDB. Do I need `mongod.conf` to use? I'm not using this file and only use URI in the `env` file. I do the netest and the there's no problem w/ mongoDb as well. Please explain me as I'm just new to infra part.

Answer (score 0):

In order to connect your Azure Container Instance to your VM hosting Mongo DB, make sure you have a Vnet with 2 subnets as you cannot create ACI inside the VM subnet.

[image]

Once created, you can verify the same under `subnet tab` of the vnet as below
[image]

Make sure your VM is placed under `subnet1`, and Container Instance is placed under `subnet2` while creating them.
[image]

[image]
[image]

Now under containers tab of your container instance, you can connect to the VM using it's private IP as below-

```
nc <Private-IP_addr_of_your_VM> <port_no>
```

[image]